# python .format not working as expected

Tags: python, format

This makes no sense to me. I define 5 variables:

```
a='a'
b='b'
c='c'
d='d'
e='e'
```

Then I try to build a command using those variables:

```
command = "for i in \`python {0}_getSyslogs.py {1} {2} {3}\`\ndo\ngunzip -c {3}/\$i | egrep -i '{4}' >> " .format(a,b,c,d,e)
```

This works as expected, with the resulting command:

```
"for i in \\`python a_getSyslogs.py b c d\\`\ndo\ngunzip -c d/\\$i | egrep -i 'e' >> "
```

What gets me is if I add one more component to the string (ie "test"), the whole thing falls apart in that there is no more substitution going on:

```
command = "for i in \`python {0}_getSyslogs.py {1} {2} {3}\`\ndo\ngunzip -c {3}/\$i | egrep -i '{4}' >> " + "test" .format(a,b,c,d,e)
```

The resulting command is as follow:

```
"for i in \\`python {0}_getSyslogs.py {1} {2} {3}\\`\ndo\ngunzip -c {3}/\\$i | egrep -i '{4}' >> test"
```

This is probably a "can't see the forest through the trees" problem, but I've been trying all kinds of different combinations and nothing works.

I'm running python 2.7.10 on CentOS:

> > > sys.version
> > >       '2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is trying to build a shell command using string formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `(command+"test").format(a,b,c,d,e)` i.e. putting it in parentheses. Your current approach only uses format on `"test"`

Comment: This one worked for me and appears to be the simplest. I understand the subprocess proposed by chepner (thanks for that) as well. Problem is I'm building the command then sending to a different node using pexpect.

Answer (score 2):

You are applying the `format` function only on the "test" string.

Try:

```
command = "for i in \`python {0}_getSyslogs.py {1} {2} {3}\`\ndo\ngunzip -c {3}/\$i | egrep -i '{4}' >> test" .format(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just,

```
"... >> test".format(a,b,c,d,e)
```

instead of

```
"... >> " + "test".format(a,b,c,d,e)
```

---

`.format` is only applicable to one `string` object and you are applying it to `"test"`.

If you *really* want to concat two strings, first store them in a variable and then do what you need to do.

```
str1 = "example{} " + "test"
str1.format('3')
# example3 test
```

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, don't try to fill in a string template to build a command, as you are unlikely to get the quoting correct. Instead, do as much in Python as possible, using the `subprocess` module where necessary.

```
from subprocess import Popen, call, PIPE

def processFile(name, pattern, output):
    p = Popen(["gunzip", "-c", name], stdout=PIPE)
    call(["egrep", "-i", pattern], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=output)

with open("test", "w") as fh:
    p = Popen(["python", "{0}_getSyslogs.py".format(a), b, c, d], stdout=PIPE)
    for x in p.stdout:
        x = x.strip()
        processFile(os.path.join(d, x), e, fh)
```